# Background image in applications running on Xoom tablet

Tags: android, resources, background-image, motorola, xoom

If I run an application on my Motorola Xoom tablet, there is an image in the background. If I run the same application on the emulator the background in my application is just black. Do you have an idea where I can get this image, which is in the background of Xoom applications?

I need it, because I took a number of screenshots of the app in the emulator for documentation purposes and it doesn't look very good with the black background.

Comment: are you sure you've set up your emulator to run the same version of Android as your xoom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This image is the window background. The default window background is specified using a [state list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html). As the image used for this is stretched - a cheap operation with hardware accelerated drawing but more expensive in software - the state list specifies this background for the [`android:state_accelerated`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#state_accelerated) case. Since the emulator does not currently support hardware accelerated drawing it gets the fallback of solid black instead.

Comment: Thank you. This explains the problem, but do you know where I can find the background image for the accelerated state? Maybe somewhere in the sdk folder?

Comment: It's a private framework resource. You could probably go digging in framework-res.jar for it, or wait for the Android 4.0 source release.

Comment: After pulling the framework-res.apk from the device and searching I just found the image in the res/drawable-nodpi folder. The name of the file is background_holo_dark.png. Thank you very much for your help adamp :)

Answer (score 0):

Just for completion, here is the image I was searching for:

[image: Here is the image]